# What algorithm does Photoshop use to desaturate an image?

Tags: algorithm, image

I have been trying to figure out what kind of mathematical algorithm that programs like Photoshop use when they desaturate each pixel of an image. By desaturate, I mean turning a colored image into a greyscale image and still maintaining the colorspace. I am still talking about an RGB image but one that has just been desaturated in color and is now black and white.

Does anyone know what kind of algorithm is used?

Comment: I should specify that I am looking for an algorithm on a per pixel level. For instance, RGB(12, 104, 22) rather than the whole image.

Comment: I hope this is useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness -- there's precious little there about RGB colorspace, but a lot of detail about other colorspaces...

Comment: Another option is to investigate the GIMP sources; there is a Desaturate tool there, too, which might be close enough for you.

Comment: I obviously don't know how Photoshop does it, but in principle you can convert a pixel's representation from RGB to HSL, reduce the saturation (the S component), then convert it back to RGB.

Comment: Easiest solution is to take the mean and place it for every color.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError, HSL is a bad choice because it doesn't account for the different brightness of the primaries. Green should convert to a lighter gray than Blue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Desaturating is pretty simple. The usual is something like `G*.59+R*.3+B*.11`

Photoshop also has a B&W conversion tool that (basically) lets you select the factor for each. For example, you can get the effect of a red filter by increasing the percentage of red, and decreasing the green and blue to match.

Comment: Yes, that's the usual formula for getting gray from a color. You can then take that and mix it proportionally with the original color to get any amount of desaturation you'd like.

Comment: This wasn't Photoshops algorithm exactly but I just used the program Photoshop as a reference. This formula ended up producing some nice results. Thanks!

Comment: The solution may have worked for you, but this is not the correct answer to the question.

Comment: @Gkills: Photoshop has at least a couple of different ways of desaturating images. This doesn't correspond to the "desaturate" menu item, but does to (one of the many) results you can get from black and white conversion. But note that the question (not just the summary) is quite general  ("programs like Photoshop", "what kind of algorithm is used"), not an extremely specific one like: "the desature menu item in Adobe Photoshop CC".

Answer (score 6):

As noted in the comments, the accepted answer is not *the* formula used by Photoshop. The real Photoshop desaturate formula is average of minimum RGB and maximum RGB components.

```
float bw = (fminf(r, fminf(g, b)) + fmaxf(r, fmaxf(g, b))) * 0.5f;
```

I believe HSL operations in Photoshop are run in min-max-hue space, so this formula is chosen for speed.

Comment: This is MUCH closer to Photoshop than the accepted answer. I'm using Unreal Engine and its built-in desaturate function produces the same results as the accepted answer. However, The default function loses the value of blue areas of an image, but both Photoshop and this formula keep them very well. Thanks!